# How can I get product information using Amazon Api with C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to make a C# application that gets the price and some product information with the ASIN number from Amazon. With Html Agility Pack, I can directly look at the web page and fetch some information. However, it is somewhat inefficient and difficult to process some data. That's why I want to use api. But I couldn't find a working example.

I tried Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising but couldn't get any information. It throws various errors or returns null.

I created an AWS account and added a user, accesskey and secretkey. However, I am getting the following error. "The Access Key Id AKI.......TN7 is not enabled for accessing Product Advertising API."

What path should I follow for such an application?

Comment: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/troubleshooting/error-messages.html

Answer (score 1):

To use the Amazon Product Advertising API, you need to apply for access to the API, as not all AWS accounts have automatic access to it. Once you have applied and been granted access, you can then use your AWS access key and secret key to make requests to the API.

1. Apply for access to the Amazon Product Advertising API through the AWS Management Console. You will need to provide information about your use case and how you plan to use the API.
2. Once you have been granted access, you can retrieve your Access Key ID and Secret Access Key from the AWS Management Console.
3. Install the Amazon Product Advertising API SDK for C#. You can use the NuGet package manager to add the SDK to your project.
4. In your C# code, create a new instance of the Amazon Product Advertising API client, passing in your Access Key ID, Secret Access Key, and the region where you want to make requests. For example:

```
    var credentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials("accesskey", "secretkey");
    var config = new AmazonProductAdvertisingAPIConfig { RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2 };
    var client = new AmazonProductAdvertisingClient(credentials, config);
```

5. Use the client object to make requests to the Amazon Product Advertising API. For example, you can use the `ItemLookup` operation to retrieve product information based on an ASIN:

```
var request = new ItemLookupRequest
{
    ItemId = new List<string> { "B002QYW8LW" }, // ASIN
    ResponseGroup = "Large"
};

var response = client.ItemLookup(request);
var item = response.Items[0].Item;

Console.WriteLine($"Title: {item.ItemAttributes.Title}");
Console.WriteLine($"Price: {item.OfferSummary.LowestNewPrice.FormattedPrice}");
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply but still no results. I tried again after a long time but it doesn't work.

I don't quite understand what you said in point 1. I think you are talking about API gateway. But there are too many options and configuration settings. I need a little more detailed explanation. I would really appreciate if you can help.